# Webpack string replace loader not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm bundling my project with webpack. In order to manipulate some of the files I've to replace specific values in a certain node-module. To achieve that I'm using the string-replace-loader. I added the following code to my webpack config without success.

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'string-replace',
    query: {
      search: '[MouseEvent]',
      replace: '[]'
    }
  }
```

In the bundeld file the string is not replaced. The files are within the folder node_modules/ng2-bootstrap. so may i have to specify this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `include: [/node_modules\/module_name/]` because webpack by default exclude node_modules.

But while reading an issue for similar problems, probably you must use "exclude, include" like this:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'string-replace',
  exclude: /node_modules(?!\/module_name)/
  query: {
    search: '[MouseEvent]',
    replace: '[]'
  }
}
```

if you want read the issue, [go here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031).

EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:

after some tried, i've done this (with an other plugin, but seems like yours), i've done that with this code:

```
  preLoaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
        replacements: [
          {
            pattern: /.*?(react).*?/ig,
            replacement: function (match, p1, offset, string) {
              console.log("found");
              return "found";
            }
          }
        ]}),
      include: /node_modules\\react.*/
    }
  ],
```

it might works on loaders, i've but on preloaders because i already have a loader for js.
Note that the error was on regex of include/exclude

Comment: thx for your answer. But I'm bit confused first you wrote include but in the example it is exclude. I guess it exclude, because you said node_modules is excluded by default and with (?!\/module_name) just the specific module is included I guess. I tried several variations now without success

Comment: i've cited the second method after i've watched the issue linked. have you tried the "exclude method"?

Comment: I've tried both  include: [/node_modules\/ng2-bootstrap/] and exclude: [/node_modules(?!\/ng2-bootstrap)/]. For testing I put the whole module into a libs folder. Then I get the following error message

 ERROR in ./custom_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js
    Module parse failed: /node_modules/string-replace-loader/index.js?{"search":"[MouseEvent]","replace":"[]","flags":"g"}!/custom_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js Unexpected token (2:2)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

node_modules is ignored at all, but the loader has another problem anyway

Comment: I tried also the plugin you've used and changed the pattern to /.*?(MouseEvent).*?/ig but now I'm getting several errors like:    ERROR in ./~/ng2-bootstrap/components/rating/rating.module.js
    Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

I tried to use it as preLoaders and loaders configuration with the same error

Comment: ok, the plugin it's work :) you're problem now is on replacing, what you want to replace exactly?

Comment: ok seems not to work, but let's assume that :D ... as stated in my post, I've to replace [MouseEvent] with [] ... so really with square brackets, because within the module it is an array of events. I tried  /.*?([MouseEvent]).*?/ig but it is not found at all, I don't see any console.logs

Comment: in a regular expression, the square brackets are special chars, then if you want to match it you must escape the char (example here https://regex101.com/r/iDIxRQ/1 ).